# `useForm` is not connected to any Form element

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMQma.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EF1Kn.png)

I've imported the Form from ant design, then I've declared it, and I've added the form in the Form element. but why still error occurs when rendered.

I want everything to run normally without error messages.

Comment: don't post pictures, post the errors as text, and the code. And show what you've already done.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

based on the error you provide in your question it seems that you are using useForm hook but you didn't call it , to fix this error make sure you import useForm:

```
import { useForm } from 'antd';
```